# Concept definition requiring a constrained template member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

*Note: everything that follows uses the Concepts TS implementation in GCC 6.1*

Let's say I have a concept `Surface`, like the following:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Surface() {
    return requires(T& t, point2f p, float radius) {
        { t.move_to(p) };
        { t.line_to(p) };
        { t.arc(p, radius) };
        // etc...
    };
}
```

Now I want to define another concept, `Drawable`, which matches any type with a member function:

```
template <typename S>
    requires Surface<S>()
void draw(S& surface) const;
```

i.e.

```
struct triangle {
    void draw(Surface& surface) const;
};

static_assert(Drawable<triangle>(), ""); // Should pass
```

That is, a `Drawable` is something which has a templated const member function `draw()` taking an lvalue reference to something which satisfies the `Surface` requirements. This is reasonably easy to specify in words, but I can't quite work out how to do it in C++ with the Concepts TS. The "obvious" syntax doesn't work:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Drawable() {
    return requires(const T& t, Surface& surface) {
        { t.draw(surface) } -> void;
    };
}
```

> error: 'auto' parameter not permitted in this context

Adding a second template parameter allows the concept definition to compile, but:

```
template <typename T, Surface S>
concept bool Drawable() {
    return requires(const T& t, S& s) {
        { t.draw(s) };
    };
}

static_assert(Drawable<triangle>(), "");
```

> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   couldn't deduce template parameter 'S'

now we can only check whether a particular <`Drawable`, `Surface`> *pair* matches the `Drawable` concept, which isn't quite right. (A type `D` either has the required member function or it does not: that doesn't depend on which particular `Surface` we check.)

I'm sure it's possible to do what I'm after, but I can't work out the syntax and there aren't too many examples online yet. Does anybody know how to write a concept definition which requires type to have a constrained template member function?

Comment: Have you tried using std::is_member_function_pointer<Surface> within the concepts definition? Might work. Cannot check right here as I have not installed gcc at work...

Comment: Possibly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659382/specifying-a-concept-for-a-type-that-has-a-member-function-template-using-concep?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is for a way for the compiler to synthesize an *archetype* of `Surface`. That is, some private, anonymous type that minimally satisfies the `Surface` concept. As minimally as possible. Concepts TS doesn't currently allow for a mechanism for automatically synthesizing archetypes, so we're left with doing it manually. It's quite a [complicated process](https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/things-you-can-almost-mostly-do-with-concepts-6b52ace78630), since it's very easy to come up with archetype candidates that have way more functionality that the concept specifies.

In this case, we can come up with something like:

```
namespace archetypes {
    // don't use this in real code!
    struct SurfaceModel {
        // none of the special members
        SurfaceModel() = delete;
        SurfaceModel(SurfaceModel const& ) = delete;
        SurfaceModel(SurfaceModel&& ) = delete;
        ~SurfaceModel() = delete;
        void operator=(SurfaceModel const& ) = delete;
        void operator=(SurfaceModel&& ) = delete;

        // here's the actual concept
        void move_to(point2f );
        void line_to(point2f );
        void arc(point2f, float);
        // etc.
    };

    static_assert(Surface<SurfaceModel>());
}
```

And then:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool Drawable() {
    return requires(const T& t, archetypes::SurfaceModel& surface) {
        { t.draw(surface) } -> void;
    };
}
```

These are valid concepts, that probably work. Note that there's a lot of room for even more refinement on the `SurfaceModel` archetype. I have a specific function `void move_to(point2f )`, but the concept just requires that it's callable with an lvalue of type `point2f`. There's no requirement that `move_to()` and `line_to()` both take an argument of type `point2f`, they could both take complete different things:

```
struct SurfaceModel {    
    // ... 
    struct X { X(point2f ); };
    struct Y { Y(point2f ); };
    void move_to(X );
    void line_to(Y );
    // ...
};
```

This kind of paranoia makes for a better archetype, and serves to illustrate how complex this problem could be.