# Specifying a concept for an object with a member function that returns a constrained value

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to wrap my mind around C++ 20 concept and constraint by porting some of my old code.

```
struct Status
{
    std::string status;
    std::time_t statusDate;
};

struct CurrentStatusStack
{
    std::vector<Status> statusVec;
    std::vector<std::filesystem::path> ticketPathVec;
};

void setBar(CurrentStatusStack s)
{
    ui->setLatestStatusMessage(s.statusVec.back().status);
    ui->setLatestStatusMessagePath(s.ticketPathVec.back());
}
```

To translate the above code block to a similar but generic function `setFoo(const T& t)` and to make sure `T` type implements function that `setBar` requires I wrote a few concepts:

1. A `ContainerOf` concept

```
/*
  `ContainerOf` requires container (could be a vector or a set
  or other STL-like containers) to implement at least:
  1. `cbegin()` that returns a const iterator pointer to the first element.
  2. `empty()` an emptiness check fn.
*/
template <class Container, typename T>
concept ContainerOf = requires(Container a, T)
{
  requires std::regular<Container>;
  requires std::same_as<typename Container::value_type, T>;
  {
    a.cbegin()
    } -> std::same_as<typename Container::const_iterator>;
  {
    a.empty()
    } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};
```

2. A `HasTicketPaths` concept

```
/*
  `HasTicketPaths` ensures that that structure given implements a `getTicketPaths`
  function that returns a container that satisfies `ContainerOf` with
  `std::filesystem::path` elements in it.
 */
template <typename T>
concept HasTicketPaths = requires(T t)
{
  {
    t.getTicketPaths()
    } -> ContainerOf<fs::path>;
};
```

3. A `IsStatus` concept

```
/*
  To set status the obj needs at least two elements:
  1. Status string and
  2. the date the status was posted,
  `IsStatus` ensure those constrients by requiring `status` and
  `statusDate` functions that return a `std::string` and `std::time_t`
  respectively.
*/
template <typename T>
concept IsStatus = requires(T t)
{
  {
    t.status()
    } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
  {
    t.statusDate()
    } -> std::same_as<std::time_t>;
};
```

Now I think all have to do is somehow combine those two concepts in `HasStatus` concept and change the function prototype to

```
template <typename T>
requires HasStatus<T> && requires HasTicketPaths<T>
void setFoo(const T& t);
```

but I am not sure how to do that.

I imagined it'd look something like this

```
/*
  `HasStatus` ensures that the container has a `getStatus` function that return
  a container with each element type ensuring `IsStatus`'s requirement.
 */
template <typename T>
concept HasStatus = requires(T t)
{
  {
    t.getStatus()
  } -> ContainerOf<IsStatus>;
};
```

but it generates the following error

```
invalid use of ‘decltype(auto) [requires ::IsStatus<<placeholder>, >]’ in template argument
   70 |   } -> ContainerOf<IsStatus>;
```

I think I misunderstood how `concepts` actually work but I am not sure where/what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concept is not a **type**, so it can’t appear as a container element type—neither in the type of an object (this is why you have to use `std::vector<std::any>` to approximate `std::vector<std::copyable>`) nor in the type for your concept `ContainerOf`.  Moreover, you can’t use a concept as a **template argument**, so you can’t have a higher-order `ContainerLike` concept.

What you can do is make a `Container` concept that checks only for `empty`, add the constraint

```
{ *c.cbegin() } -> IsStatus;
```

and apply it to `t.getStatus()` in another concept.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly, is this the way you suggest it https://godbolt.org/z/oo11o4jsx

Comment: @atis: Looks reasonable—I just wanted, like you ended up doing, to not mess with `HasTicketPaths` to illustrate it.

Answer (score 0):

To help others that may stumble upon this question (or future me), following is a minimal complete/reproducible example for the way I ended up implementing that

```
#include <concepts>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept IsStatus = requires(T t) {
  { t.getStatus() } -> std::same_as<const std::string&>;
  { t.getStatusDate() } -> std::same_as<const std::time_t&>;
};

template <class Container>
concept ContainerOfStatus = requires(Container c) {
  { c.empty() } -> std::same_as<bool>;
  { *c.cbegin() } -> IsStatus;
};

template <typename T>
concept HasStatus = requires(T t) {
  { t.getAllStatus() } -> ContainerOfStatus;
};

struct Status {
  std::string status;
  std::time_t statusDate;

  const std::string& getStatus() const { return status; };
  const std::time_t& getStatusDate() const { return statusDate; };
};

struct CurrentStatusStack {
  std::vector<Status> statusVec;

  const std::vector<Status>& getAllStatus() const { return statusVec; };
};

template <typename T>
requires HasStatus<T>
void printStatus(T t) {
  std::cout << t.getAllStatus().cbegin()->getStatus() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  Status s{"some status", std::time_t(nullptr)};

  CurrentStatusStack st;

  st.statusVec.push_back(s);

  std::cout << st.getAllStatus().cbegin()->getStatus() << std::endl;

  printStatus(st);
}
```

on [godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbeV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhBuGVIAB1QhQnNaO0cXN14YuLM6Hz9ApxCwiKNME0zaBgJmYgIk51d3IpKE8sqCbIDg0PDIoQqqmpT6npa23PyugEojVAdiZA4pHQBmX2RHLABqTUWbNFo5qIIhLexNGQBBJZW1zE3t0zwnTGPTi%2B1lvevbm3Me4kxmJzPc6XD4ODZbGy/XzAIGvd6rME3CEAN0wphIsJeBEwTiiqmxXwIAE8olYATcACqw3b7AjrACSQmaBAcQluABF1n8AI4OPB/IQQCnrAjjTYAdn053WEt0IoAdMBMIwKizBWLNOLOQBaY7rHroEAgITkgD6zCOdzoPX1BENxoIxGhOgAbM9FlKzjLNXKCIrlczWezmNiIBqtetdYtsLb7SbHubLTtrXSDUazAmCK73Z7NeytrnztjcfikXdVEI2XZ6MxfKFqXRaetqxU68QAPJUQNsracnl8gUQFu1vzEdbIcOe72S8fynEHIlhiU6vVp41mi0QoKoew5l7TuUAKmQ8uQIWAviXecjesZ3YLLzzD%2BBRfnpcJJLJj3WVOjLxpmAHOsAASFrdhyXKYLy/KYIKwqirK%2B6ygqSoEGcrCsN2V4RlGMbDm2nb3h6j5as%2BFznL8DimOs4E%2Bkha5QuotohqyZEymuGaYKaqaqkGIZPMRL5euOKaxkajEwtoLrrKhWFirsNo%2BpBLLELQzFqgWy5sSJtA2hxDxcVmUkyQGvFCMGobyaJSl/CpalDGqFkCXKT6CRcpFuS8lHUTYMx/PQ3bNMgADWiHSmJICouixAQkRMYOayABqaJkUhCk8faUVEDF2xxa6JloRhck6YpM62TM9lmclWgelpnkeYWZzFni/EfqStDkj%2BsL9jBbKgUyZkQr%2BJznMiqB4Og6xRE6AVmUKIqTvRdpGmgDh0hCEIocq6GYXN4ynuel7jLhsl7V8m1rp4rCpaRQm%2BHSTgjthU40WZ%2Bp0do2hCKg34JUcn2kBFnHcRAtAOBhBzEOMrmNTKvnEP5KosQNzAhbaqXhT08p/dV8pRKyCCmkEqPBRAQjQ55mPLSg0zrdsF1%2BqhO1yQdmAXrQYYnaZyNXvT2wRVdGPCdN91YT0FO5lqUiTKw0gAKzyK4sjyKg0g2AYBj6tMsxIm8nDyAQ0hyOMkzBeEnDygAnHLESfZbAAc9tyzIcvinLKjSNwitGyr0jyEIICRIbyuTHAsBIGguJ4OwZAUBAkdRNHnTAJwqd8NH2LEAHEBBD7pBBL4lREtI%2BukJHjz0O2tCsMXyukFgj3qOwJfyPgfz3KiAd15g4homt8xyOQ9DFC3Kh4EExBF3YWB546Dwt5M/CMCwzc8HwdAEMIYiSHXSicCoagaBrehj0EAeQJMqAHAkXfagavZaHoBjaDIkZUABBxCNq%2BDMMAtCxGYZAX8sAHAQL2L2DQ0SlEsNYforh96eBGB0MI%2B90jxDoHA5QaDShILyJ0fexgoFNF6NUewtRlCEPuHQZoVRcFjAISQzBDDhh1lGPgyY30ZhzC4DLeW3s66qykOIe2LptQum4DJZAyB1ip3lJwdYEBcCEBIJsPWgM7BRxjqoxYnAxTqyfnoA2PtQ5IFpvjAg5BKAJyTig0gmB8DZWUEvJgbAOBryXlvCQecADuk8ogLw9lIBWpAlaD0EUseR3jCAIHWMI0R4jJHSNkaXYOxtTYgDlvbeUMhuBy0tuKcUMhU7cEttwbQ7tZZSAgaE32Uh/bKFSdLXhUhtD8LCX7UgjSTakFRFnBI4QgA%3D%3D)

Here's another very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655113/concept-definition-requiring-a-constrained-template-member-function)