# C++ concepts: Some signatures function conversion

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

Unfortunately, the only tutorial that I have found about `concepts` was the concept lite tutorial (and it was really basic). And even with the technical specification, there is some signatures function that I don't know how translate into concepts (*maybe just because my English is bad and I can't read the technical specification really well*).

So there is a list of signatures function I still don't know how to "*translate*":

*CFoo --> class CFoo {};*

- `void Foo1() const;`
- `CFoo& Foo2();`
- `void  Foo3(CFoo&);`
- `{static, friend, ... } void Foo4();`
- `template < typename ... Args > 
  void Foo5(Args && ... args);`

**I want to have some kind of interface for a class with these functions.**
Don't even know if it's possible at this point. Foo2 and Foo3 seems to be the same problem.

---

Honestly I really want to know Foo2 and Foo5.

I tried somethings, for the Foo2 but I don't have any idea about Foo5:

```
class Handle {};

template < typename Object >
concept bool C_Object =
  requires(Handle handle) {
    {get(handle)} -> Object&
  };

template < C_Object Object >
class Foo {

  Object obj;
};

int main() {

  Foo<int>  test;
  return 0;
}
```

I know this won't compile because Foo don't have a get menber, but these are not the right errors:

```
Test1.cpp:6:16: error: there are no arguments to ‘get’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘get’ must be available [-fpermissive]
     {get(handle)} -> Object&
                ^
Test1.cpp:6:16: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
Test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Test1.cpp:18:10: error: template constraint failure
   Foo<int>  test;
          ^
Test1.cpp:18:10: note:   constraints not satisfied
Test1.cpp:4:14: note: within ‘template<class Object> concept const bool C_Object<Object> [with Object = int]’
 concept bool C_Object =
              ^~~~~~~~
Test1.cpp:4:14: note:     with ‘Handle handle’
Test1.cpp:4:14: note: the required expression ‘get(handle)’ would be ill-formed
```

If someone can point me out some resources or, why not, a solution. It will be great.

Have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know this won't compile because Foo don't have a get menber […]

Concepts deal with normal expressions. In particular, the scope of `requires` expressions is normal scope, not class scope. This may be more apparent with this concept:

```
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
concept bool Addable = requires(Lhs lhs, Rhs rhs) {
    lhs + rhs;
};
```

`Addable<int, long>` is fulfilled because given `int lhs; long rhs;` then `lhs + rhs` is a valid expression. We're using the built-in addition operator on two (pretend) variables we explicitly introduced in the parameter list, not calling a member `operator+` on an implicit `*this`.

Concepts are about interfaces in the wider sense (as in 'API'), not in a narrower OOP sense. You can think of `Addable` as a relation on pairs of types. That `Addable<int, long>` holds doesn't mean `int` on its own has a special relationship with `Addable`. It is true that `Addable` can be used as e.g.

```
template<Addable<long> Var>
struct client {
    Var var;
};
```

and then `client<int>` comes with an `Addable<int, long>` constraint, but this shortcut is syntactical in nature. It's a helpful way of cutting down boilerplate, namely sparing us from writing `template<typename Var> requires Addable<Var, long>`.

With that in mind, here are some expressions that may come close to checking the member signatures you mentioned, plus the `Handle` scenario:

```
template<typename Obj>
concept bool Object = requires(Obj obj, Obj const cobj, Handle handle) {
    cobj.Foo1();
    { obj.Foo2() } -> Obj&;
    obj.Foo3(obj);
    // static
    Obj::Foo4();
    // non-member, possibly friend
    Foo4(obj);

    { obj.get(handle) } -> Obj&;
};
```

(I elided the `Foo5` scenario because it's worth its own question, here is a [lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659382/specifying-a-concept-for-a-type-that-has-a-member-function-template-using-concep).)

Comment: You're right, I was blind about concept and class. Thanks a lot.
I'll try that and close the question if you think that Foo5 is too out of the scope.